# Unresolved reference DaggerApplicationComponent

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2

I'm trying to create my app component, but Dagger does not generate my app component.
here is **MyApplication** class

```
class MyApplication : Application() {

companion object {
    @JvmStatic lateinit var graph: ApplicationComponent
}
@Inject
lateinit var locationManager : LocationManager

override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    graph = DaggerApplicationComponent.builder().appModule(AppModule(this)).build()
    graph.inject(this)
  }
}
```

and here is my **AppComponent** class

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = arrayOf(AppModule::class))
interface ApplicationComponent {
    fun inject(application: MyApplication)
}
```

here is screenshot
[image]

this is my [project](https://github.com/developer--/Where_is_WIFI) on **github**

here is error log

```
Error:(7, 48) Unresolved reference: DaggerApplicationComponent
Error:(28, 17) Unresolved reference: DaggerApplicationComponent
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.
> Compilation error. See log for more details
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 21.184 secs
Error:e: .../MyApplication.kt: (7, 48): Unresolved reference: DaggerApplicationComponent
e: Unresolved reference: DaggerApplicationComponent
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.
> Compilation error. See log for more details

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

Information:4 errors
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

Comment: What does it say when you try to build the app?

Comment: I have updated my question

Comment: @user5543258 did you solve your issue? I have the same problem.

Comment: nothing working here, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 52):

my solution is to add

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
```

and remove

```
kapt {
    generateStubs = true
}
```

Comment: This save my live.

Comment: Seriously I was stuck for last one day, unfortunately didn't searched. It helped me a lot.

Answer (score 49):

This helped me to fix this issue

Add this in the top of the `build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
```

Inside `android` tag add

```
kapt {
    generateStubs = true
}
```

And then replace

```
annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.11'
```

to

```
kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.11'
```

Now `Rebuild` the project by

```
Build -> Rebuild project
```

Comment: I think you should remove `generateStubs = true`

Answer (score 29):

Please try enabling [stubs generation](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2015/06/better-annotation-processing-supporting-stubs-in-kapt/), this might be the reason why the class is not visible at this stage of the build process. In your `build.gradle` file, top level:

```
kapt {
    generateStubs = true
}
```

Comment: What about Java version??

Answer (score 7):

I've already downloaded your Github project. Thanks for sharing!

**The answer for your issue is pretty simple:**

```
Build -> Rebuild project
```

Dagger dependencies files will be recreated and app after would launched with any problem.

I checked already this with Android Studio 2.1.2 version. It works

Answer (score 5):

you should remove

```
kapt {
generateStubs = true}
```

and add to the top of application gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
```

then Dagger will take care of the rest :)

Answer (score 4):

Add this on Top of build.gradlle

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
```

Add this in Dependencies

```
kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.15'
kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.15'
```

After that rebuild your project . i hope it will work.
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

In my case missing kapt compiler dependency. Please make sure to have below dependency too.

```
kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.15'
```

app build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.usb.utility"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.15'
    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.15' // if you use the support libraries
    kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.15'
    kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.15'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In the new version of hilt, you need to use SingletonComponent::class instead of ApplicationComponent::class

Answer (score 2):

Also for Java users, the solution is simply to **Rebuild** your project.

Comment: This is perfect solution

Answer (score 2):

Answer is simple :

`Build -> Rebuild project`

It works for me.

Answer (score 2):

Only two steps should be required for mixed Java/Kotlin projects:

1. Add `apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'` to the top of the build file
2. Replace `annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.14.1'` with `kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.14.1'`

Answer (score 1):

For anyone using the newest Dagger version (above 2.30):

`ApplicationComponent` has been **replaced by `SingletonComponent`**.

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
class RoomModule() {
   . . .
}
```

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65991420/13366254).

Answer (score 0):

Please try adding this to your `build.gradle`

```
android {
    dexOptions {
        incremental false
    }
```

EDIT: apparently a year later this can happen if you don't apply `kotlin-kapt` plugin. Also make sure you use `kapt`instead of `annotationProcessor`.

Comment: https://github.com/developer--/Where_is_WIFI/blob/master/app/build.gradle

Comment: What happens if you remove android-apt plugin?

Comment: I'm not sure what's wrong then :( but please check [this example](https://github.com/damianpetla/kotlin-dagger-example) and see if there's any difference and if the "known limitations" here match your issue

Answer (score 0):

In my case `Rebuild` didn't help. I injected two dependencies in `<module>` component (BookComponent):

```
fun inject(fragment: ListFragment)

fun inject(fragment: NotFoundFragment)
```

When I removed one `inject`, the project had built. But both `injects` together broke build process. Then I simply swapped them:

```
fun inject(fragment: NotFoundFragment)

fun inject(fragment: ListFragment)
```

Answer (score -1):

This must solve your problem:

### Update (March 29, 2020)

Inside your **app-level** `build.gradle` inside `dependencies` block, add these lines:

```
     //dagger2
     api 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.24'
     api 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.24'
     api 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.24'

     annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.24'
     kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.24'

     annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.24'
     kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.24'

     compileOnly 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'
     implementation 'javax.inject:javax.inject:1'
```

Inside `android` block of **app-level** `build.gradle`,

```
kapt {
        generateStubs = true
    }
```

At the **top** of the **app-level** `build.gradle`, Do this in **exactly below order**.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

Finally, You need to configure Annotation Process as provided in the screenshot below. You can do this `File>Other Settings>Settings for New Projects>`search`"Annotation processor"`
[image]

After this, do from Menu `Build > Rebuild`. You are done!

**Test:**

```
@Component
public interface ApplicationComponent {

}
```

Now, you can use `DaggerApplicationComponent` that was generated at compile-time for your Applicati`o`nComponent interface.

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    ApplicationComponent applicationComponent = DaggerApplicationComponent.create();


}
```

Answer (score -1):

In my case, I did everything in al answers but did not fix it!

**my solution:** go to Directory path of your project and delete

`build`, `app>build`, `.idea` , `.Gradle`

and go back to the android studio and `rebuild` the project and Done!