# Error: Unresolved reference: DaggerAppComponent

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2

I've been facing this problem for 3 hours. I couldn't find any logical reason to what is happening. The problem is, Only when I use the generated `Dagger` classes, and after `Gradle` do the `Build` every reference to these classes became red and I get the error:

> Error: Unresolved reference: DaggerAppComponent

But, If I comment out every line in the `App` class reference any of these generated `Dagger` classes. The build process completed successfully. I tried doing clean/ rebuild/ make project. but it doesn't work.
Some information about my  environment:
`Build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxxxx"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.0"
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel:1.1.0"
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:livedata:1.1.0"
    implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0"
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.1.0"

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"

    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'


    kapt "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.1.0"
    kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0"

    kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.8"
    compile "com.google.dagger:dagger:2.8"
    compile "com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.8"

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

Kotlin version: `ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.51'`
Android Studio version: `3.0.1`

dependencies section in `Build.Gradle` file for the project (not the app module):

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

`App` class:

```
class App:Application() {
    private val component:AppComponent by lazy {
        DaggerAppComponent.builder()
                .build()
    }
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        component.inject(this)
    }
}
```

If anyone can figure out what is the problem, it would be much appreciated.
P.S. I'm still learning `Dagger2` and I'm new to `Kotlin` and `Native` development in general. I came from `C#` and `Xamarin` background.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be missing the application of the kapt Gradle plugin, as described in the [kapt documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/kapt.html). Basically, add this after your existing plugins:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
```

(If this helps, this question should be marked as a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38833242/unresolved-reference-daggerapplicationcomponent))

Comment: It worked, but why? I was having no issue with `Android Architecture component` and `Room`? Thanks a lot mate!

Comment: You are right. The question is indeed duplicate. Should I delete it? or close it (by selecting your answer) and then report it as duplicate?

Comment: Not sure why, sometimes annotation processors work without explicitly applying the plugin... That would probably deserve its own question. As for this one, I've closed it for now.

Comment: Thanks again mate!