# Kotlin - Unresolved reference: Dagger{Name}Component

Tags: kotlin, dagger-2

I'm learning how to use `Dagger 2` and `MVP` architeture.

But I'm stuck in this error now:

> Unresolved reference: DaggerHelloComponent

Look, this is my module:

```
@Module
class HelloModule {
    lateinit var activityDagger: HelloActivityDagger

    constructor(activityDagger: HelloActivityDagger) {
        this.activityDagger = activityDagger
    }

    @Provides
    fun providesHelloPresenter(): HelloActivityPresenterDagger = HelloActivityPresenterDagger(activityDagger)
}
```

and my component:

```
@Component(modules = [HelloModule::class])
interface HelloComponent {
    fun inject(activityDagger: HelloActivityDagger)
}
```

So when I try to builder this component like this `DaggerHelloComponent.create().inject(this)` in my `HelloActivityDagger` shows me the error above.

Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Cause I can see whats wrong in this code.

Oh, I already have followed this `kapt` things from this question [Unresolved reference DaggerApplicationComponent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38833242/unresolved-reference-daggerapplicationcomponent) and nothing happens

**EDIT**

To be more readable I`ve uploaded my project to Git. https://github.com/luangs7/DaggerMvpExample

Comment: Did you build your project after configuring `kapt`? Your first build will of course fail, but it should generate the Dagger class for you to import and use from there on.

Comment: yes, I`ve rebuild the project several times after

Comment: have you add `apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'`, because kapt is deprecated in default gradle. So you need to add mentioned plugin in order to kapt needs to work.

Comment: Just to add a small note on this issue, remember to check everywhere you have `@Inject` in your app. Note that you cannot inject into private fields. If you have `@Inject private lateinit var ...` you'll have this error even if your components and modules have been properly setup.

Answer (score 0):

Putting this code in the `MyApplication` class works for me to create the module starting off from your GitHub project - after the first failed build, `kapt` generates the `DaggerHelloComponent` class, and I can import it.

```
import android.app.Application
import br.com.squarebits.mvpexample.DaggerMvp.componentes.DaggerHelloComponent
import br.com.squarebits.mvpexample.DaggerMvp.componentes.HelloComponent
import br.com.squarebits.mvpexample.DaggerMvp.modules.HelloModule

class MyApplication : Application() {

    val component: HelloComponent by lazy {
        DaggerHelloComponent.builder()
                .helloModule(HelloModule(HelloActivityDagger()))
                .build()
    }

}
```

If this is not happening at all, you should try the usual debugging steps of restarting Studio with `File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart`, cleaning and rebuilding your project, etc. Perhaps try pulling the GitHub repo to a new location and see if that builds for you - the code isn't the problem.